# Change return value: list of tuples to objects, and keep backward compatibilty

Tags: python, tuples, backwards-compatibility

Imagine there is a method which returns a list of tuples:

```
[(a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2), ...]
```

The library is in wide spread use and you don't want to break existing code.

You want to change from tuples to objects, since you want to add an new (but optional) value.

Changing to  `[(a1, b1, c1, d1), (a2, b2, c2, d1), ...]` would break existing code.

What can I do?

Comment: Introduce a new method and phase out the old one slowly?

Comment: You'd add a new method that replaces the old. Mark the old as deprecated, use the `warnings` module at some point, then remove it entirely in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that extends the built-in tuple type, add an attribute to that class, and return instances of that class instead of plain tuples. The old code will continue to work, and the new code will be able to access the attributes.

```
class MyTuple(tuple): pass
t = MyTuple((1, 2, 3))
t.d1 = "my new attribute"
```